# Non-measurable subset of a null set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading measure theory,and I am searching an example in which a measurable null set have a non-measurable subset because this is the reason that,s why we are studying about complete measure.Please If someone have any information about it share with me???
Thanks.

Comment: So, do you need a Lebesgue-measurable which isn't Borel-measurable?

Comment: I need a non-measurable subset of a null set with respect to same measure.

Comment: or in other words I am searching for an example of incomplete measure space.

Comment: If you just need an example: Let $X=\{1,\,2,\,3\}$ and the let the $\sigma$-algebra of the measurable sets consisting only the subsets $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$. Suppose $\lambda$ is a measure over this $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda(\{2,3\})=0$. Now, we have shown a set with zero measure, having a non-measurable subset.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what measure you want to consider, so I'll pick one: Borel measure on the reals. The Cantor middle thirds set has zero Borel measure and it contains non-Borel measurable subsets. One way to prove this last claim is to make use of the fact that there are only $c$ many Borel subsets of the real line, while there are $2^c$ many subsets of the Cantor middle thirds set.

This is probably the example @Édes István Gergely had in mind in his comment (if asked to be more specific), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Take the devil staircase $\psi:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ and consider the function $x+\psi(x)$. This map is strictly increasing from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$, and thus it is an homeomorphism, and it maps the cantor set in a set of zero measure. Take a non measurable set in the image of the cantor set (which exists since its image through $x+\psi$ has measure $1$) and consider its preimage. It is therefore a non Borel set contained in a null set on the line. This answer your question completely.